# How to make left column div take reaming space and right column takes the content width?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like

[image]

here the left div should take the remaining width and the right div (probably floated) div to take content width.

is it possible to achieve this without using `flex`?

Comment: Yes, with `grid`.

Comment: the content width is not known.

Comment: "is it possible to achieve this without using flex?" — On what basis are you rejecting the tool designed for the this job? We rather need to know otherwise any solution might be rejected for the same reason.

Comment: @Quentin I want to make this some at presentable in the IE also.

Comment: Then your question should be about making it work in IE and not about making it work without Flexbox (and you shouldn't care about making it work in IE because it is an obsolete piece of junk that is only kept around so that businesses using ancient and out of data intranet applications that depend on it can keep using their intranet applications).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS grid here, which offers a new type of unit `fr` (which is one ***fr**action* of the *remaining width*).

```css
article {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  padding: 2px;
}

aside {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

main {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <aside>Takes remaining width.</aside>
  <main>Takes content width.</main>
</article>

<article>
  <aside>Takes remaining width.</aside>
  <main>Takes content width. If this gets wider, aside gets narrower.</main>
</article>
```